# Is belief in the end of experience wrong view according to the Buddha?

Tags: pali-canon

I read on the internet the following opinion:

> *... the view that death marks the end of experiencing, that death is the end of experience... this, according to the Buddha, is wrong
>   view.*

However, Dhammapada 41 states:

> Vata  Alas! Ayam kåyo  This body, Aciram  Cannot endure. Apetaviñ
>   Apetaviññåno  When consciousness is gone, Chuddho  They throw it away,
>   Adhisessati Adhisessati  To lie,   Pathavi Pathavim  Upon the earth
>   Kalimgaram iva  Like a fallen log, Nirattham Useless,
>   meaningless ...

Also, the last words of the Buddha from DN 16 are:

> *"Behold now, bhikkhus, I exhort you: All compounded things are subject to vanish. Strive with earnestness!"*

If experience did not end at the termination of life, why would Dhp 41 use the word "Alas!"?

If experience did not vanish at the termination of life, why should a Buddhist practitioner strive with earnestness?

Comment: Why should he strive if experience ends at termination of life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember now the sutta name, maybe colleagues can help me with the quote, this is inexact :

To one who see the arising aspect of the world with wisdom there is no anihilationist view and to one who see the passing away aspect of the world there is no eternalist view.

Comment: Sutta sounds like SN 12.15 https://suttacentral.net/en/sn12.15 .